# In the terminal in VSCode there's too much white space

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open the terminal in VSCode, there's too much white space.

[image: too much white space in VSCode]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

I have to press Enter to type the command. Has anyone encountered this error?

[image: See image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57803

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but this is what fixed it for me:

- Configure VSCode to use cmd.exe as the terminal (settings.json):

  `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",`
- Open cmd.exe
- Go to default settings
- Make sure `"[V] Use legacy console"` is checked
- OK, OK, restart VSCode

I guess you'll lose some new console features, but I don't use any of them anyway, so for me - this solved the problem.

I noticed the same problem with PS and other console implementations (because the root cause is likely here: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/270, as people here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57803 eventually realized), but at least I found a way to solve it with cmd.exe.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the height of the terminal at the bottom (so that it occupies a large amount of the screen), then you kill the terminal and then Right-click to run Python file in Terminal, it will work.  It is a Terminal rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you encountered a temporary glitch that got resolved after restarting Visual Studio Code (VSCode)