# Problem running code in VS code via Code run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When running Python code in VS code via Code run, for some reason the path to the file is not completely highlighted and because of this, apparently the terminal produces empty lines and only then the result of the program. Please help me solve this problem.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QKft.jpg)

I tried fiddling with the settings, but it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, get started using https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Execution command needs to have a valid path, as long as it is correct, green string highlight shouldn't matter. The issue is possibly with non-ASCII English characters used in the path naming, you can try using just ASCII characters to ensure the string is recognizable by Python exe.

Comment: agree with @HarshitGupta.  the non ASCII is a red flag...

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53798381/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55060892/11107541

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing the workspace path to English and removing spaces between words.